# ImportError: cannot import name argpartsort

Tags: python

I have a python script which import the bottleneck as follow:

```
from bottleneck import argpartsort
```

I have the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name argpartsort
```

I have installed python bottleneck package from the [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bottleneck) and tested a simple program and it execute successfully. However, I still encountered the above mentioned error for another script. I am not including the python script in the post because the error is in script statement `from bottleneck import argpartsort`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this would help:

> Functions partsort and argpartsort have been renamed to partition and
>   argpartition to match NumPy. Additionally the meaning of the input
>   arguments have changed: bn.partsort(a, n) is now equivalent to
>   bn.partition(a, kth=n-1). Similarly for bn.argpartition.

from [here](http://berkeleyanalytics.com/bottleneck/release.html)

So, now it would be like:

```
from bottleneck import argpartition
```

Comment: yeah sure. Thanks.

Comment: I meant to mark this question as answered and btw, you good with machine learning?